# No Internet when another Android device is connected to router

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean, internet

Like the titles says, i have a weird problem.
I have a brand new device A (Android phone V4.2, manufacturer is called "Vivax"-not very popular outside Europe), which is having problems accessing internet.

Internet works only if there is no other smartphones connected to router.If the other phone (some older Samsung) is connected, there is no internet access on the device A.If i disconnect the Samsung device, turn wifi off and back on on device A, it can browse internet.
But if the other phone is connected, there is no internet access at all.

I checked the router and i think it is using WPA2 encryption.Also, there is no IP address conflict.

Anybody have any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: *[uboat55](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/67400/uboat55) seeks clarification:* What if you reserve an IP for device A on your router?

Answer (score 0):

by reserving I guess uboat55 means to .. suggest the use of static IP address. you can configure your router to work with static IP address instead of a dhcp service.which I also feel should do the trick .

configure your router with fixed IP address and latter use that IP address.

or you can even try to assign IP address directly to ur device A. without changing any thing on the router part.

just remember the IP address range. 
eg 
192.168.1xx.xxx to 192.168.255.254

and chose any one IP address within that range .

and remember the default subnet I.e 255.255.xxx.xxx or something similar

and the router IP address and use this on ur mobile .

Comment: If you want to add more information to an answer, you do this by clicking [edit] and editing it. Don't post a whole new answer to add more information, or the page will become very hard to read!